# Does 0x0 have a balance, and if so is it always 0?

Tags: solidity, addresses, constructor

I have a condition in a contract that checks if `msg.value > patron.balance`. At the top of the contract, I declare `patron` with `address patron;`. However, it is not set in the constructor, so patron should be the default `0x0`.

Can I even call `patron.balance` if I don't set it in the constructor? And if so, can I rely on the balance of `0x0` to always be 0?

Comment: Actually, at the time of posting the balance of 0x0 is 7206 Ether: https://etherscan.io/address/0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0x0` in `Solidity` is short for `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`, which has a balance significantly greater than zero: https://etherscan.io/address/0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000.

Therefore one cannot rely on the balance of `0x0` to be zero, nor does it make sense to send funds to `0x0` within a contract as a means of "destroying" the ether in the contract (or rather, making the eth unuseable).