# Resetting address variables

Tags: solidity, addresses

How do you reset an address variable in Solidity? You cannot assign it Null or 0 but I want to be able to "deassign" an address somehow. Any ideas?

Comment: With 0x? Or 0x....0 ?

Answer (score 1):

A solution similar to the following should work:

```
contract Test {
    address public someAddr;
    function nullifySomeAddr() {
        someAddr = address(0);
    }
}
```

The above code snippet will set the `someAddr` variable to its default type, the all 0 address (0x000000000000......)

Answer (score 1):

There's no null in Solidity, but you can assign an address to **0x0**

This is practically just 0 written in hexadecimal notation.

0x0 is essentially an abbreviation for the genesis address 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000, which most likely nobody has the private key for, so I've seen that being used for nullifying an address.

Have also a look at this: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/18427/43751